# Fix Databricks SQL Query

Tags: sql, databricks

Need help with this error in Databricks:

> [DATATYPE_MISMATCH.UNEXPECTED_INPUT_TYPE] Cannot resolve "1 + (End_Date - Start_Date)" due to data type mismatch: Parameter 1 requires the "(TIMESTAMP OR TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE)" type, however "1" has the type "INT".; line 10, pos 0

```
select 
  Member_ID, 
  Enroll_Date, 
  DisEnroll_Date, 
  Plan_Premium_Amount Mth_Prem, 
  Rate_Area_ID, 
  Commercial_Plan_ID, 
  Case When substr(COMMERCIAL_PLAN_ID, 1, 10) in (
    '58185SC118', '58185SC218, ' 58185SC338, 
    '' 58185SC418
  ) Then 'IVBU' Else 'SIG' End CIG_LOB, 
  1 +(End_Date - Start_Date) Days_Cov, 
  (
    1 +(End_Date - Start_Date)
  )* Day_Amt Covg_Amt 
From 
  (
    select 
      RunDate, 
      Member_ID, 
      Enroll_Date, 
      DisEnroll_Date, 
      Plan_Premium_Amount, 
      Rate_Area_ID, 
      Commercial_Plan_ID, 
      Case when Enroll_Date > '20141231' Then To_Date(enroll_Date, 'YYYYMMDD') Else To_Date('20150101', 'YYYYMMDD') End Start_Date, 
      Case when DisEnroll_Date > '20150930' Then To_Date('20150930', 'YYYYMMDD') Else To_Date(Disenroll_Date, 'YYYYMMDD') End End_Date, 
      Plan_Premium_Amount / 30.4 Day_Amt 
    From 
      bx_rmr.rag_cig_enrollment 
    Where 
      RunDate > 20151101 
      and Enroll_Date < 20150930 
      and Disenroll_Date > 20141231
  )



Thanks!
```

Comment: Most databases provide a "date add" function, if they don't support straight arithmetic such as `date + 1`, which appears to be the case here. For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/date_add

Comment: @D.O. are you using Azure databricks?